# Does anyone know the steps needed to duplicate the authentication as used on MS Graph Explorer?

Tags: blazor-server-side, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get my app to self register on Azure. I dont want the users to have to go to their Azure portal and register my app, it would be technically challenging for them.

I know I can make calls to MS Graph to create an Application (POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications) and then save the Application Id, and use that for further calls. However, I am struggling to work out which of the flows I need to use to obtain credentials. It feels like I should be using the interactive flow, but this requires client id to work. (see code).  I have been reading the documentation for days now. I have even downloaded sample code. Each of the examples does things in a different way, and none of them seem to actually work. I feel like I am missing something fundamental here. Can someone help?  Thanks

```
 //Interactive credentials
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#interactive-provider

            InteractiveBrowserCredential _interactiveBrowserCredential;

            CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

            var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = _settings.TenantId,
                ClientId = _settings.ClientId,
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                // MUST be http://localhost or http://localhost:PORT
                // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/System-Browser-on-.Net-Core
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:44309/"),
            };

            _interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

            _userClient = new GraphServiceClient(_interactiveBrowserCredential, _settings.Scopes);
```

```
 var app = new Application
            {
                DisplayName = "NewAppRegistration"
            };

            var x = await _userClient.Applications.Request().AddAsync(app);
```

I dont get errors, but it does nothing.

This is a Blazor server side app, that requires access to individuals personal accounts.

From other answers I have downloaded this sample from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample

Running it, tells me that

ArgumentNullException: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.

Which I dont have.

I have seen posts suggesting using MSAL to get the token to then use for MS Graph, which is fine.  Apart from MSAL needs a client id..... At least based on this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop#call-the-microsoft-graph-api-by-using-the-token-you-just-obtained  and I cant have the user register the app manually.

The error seems to occur in

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

In Startup.cs

My AzureAd section

```
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the AuthCode flow:

> ```
> //AUTH code credentials
>         //https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.authorizationcodecredential
>
>         AuthorizationCodeCredential _authCodeCredential;
>
>         string _authCode = authCode;
>
>         //Must NOT attempt silent token aquasition
>         //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens
>
>
>         //var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
>         //{
>         //    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
>         //};
>
>         var options = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions
>         {
>             AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
>             RedirectUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44307/msalsignin/")
>         };
>
>
>         _authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(_settings.TenantId, _settings.ClientId,
> ```
>
> _settings.ClientSecret, _authCode, options);
>
> ```
>         _userClient = new >GraphServiceClient(_authCodeCredential,_settings.Scopes);
> ```

And obtained the AuthCode from a call to MSAL:

> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={encodedUrl}&response_mode={responseMode}&scope={scope}&state={state}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7BclientId%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=%7BencodedUrl%7D&response_mode=%7BresponseMode%7D&scope=%7Bscope%7D&state=%7Bstate%7D)

Note the Microsoft docs use TokenCredentialOptions. This causes an 'Redirect_uri not set' error. I added in Microsoft Identity 1.8 package (Nov 2022) which has the AuthorizationCodeCredentials object (inherits tokenCredentialOptions).

This allows setting the redirect uri as shown.  and now it works.